# Why don't both 'branches' of a cyclic integral of $\sin(x)\cdot\cosh(x)$ give me an answer?

Tags: integration

I am trying to calculate  $$\mathcal{C}=\int\sin(x)\cdot\cosh(x)\;dx$$
I realized that depending on which variables i treat as the 'to be differentatied/integrated' one i get different results.

- #### case a)

$$\mathcal{C}=\sin(x)\cdot\sinh(x)-\int\cos(x)\cdot\sinh(x)\;dx=$$
$$=\sin(x)\cdot\sinh(x)-\left[\cos(x)\cdot\cosh(x)-\int-\sin(x)\cdot\cosh(x)\;dx\right]$$
$$=\sin(x)\cdot\sinh(x)-\cos(x)\cdot\cosh(x)-\underbrace{\int\sin(x)\cdot\cosh(x)\;dx}_{\mathcal{C}} $$
$$\mathcal{C}=\dfrac{\sin(x)\cdot\sinh(x)-\cos(x)\cdot\cosh(x)}{2}$$
This answer checks out.

- #### case b)

$$\mathcal{C}=\int\sin(x)\cdot\cosh(x)\;dx=\sin(x)\cdot\sinh(x)-\int\cos(x)\cdot\sinh(x)\;dx=$$
$$=\sin(x)\cdot\sinh(x)-\left[\sin(x)\cdot\sinh(x)-\underbrace{\int\sin(x)\cdot\cosh(x)\;dx}_{\mathcal{C}}\right]$$
$$=\sin(x)\cdot\sinh(x)-\sin(x)\cdot\sinh(x)+\underbrace{\int\sin(x)\cdot\cosh(x)\;dx}_{\mathcal{C}}$$
$$\mathcal{C}-\mathcal{C}=0$$
$$0=0$$

Here i just get an identity, as $\mathcal{C}$ falls out.

Did I make a mistake?

**Can i obtain a solution of a cyclic integral in only one way?** Will the other way always result in an identity?

Edit: I left out the arbitrary constants, please ignore that.

Comment: $ c$ is same capital $C$?

Comment: @Narasimham yes, they are equal, but i can't make it look bigger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't make a mistake. It's perfectly possible to do integration by parts and get back exactly the same integral. That just means your particular application of integration by parts won't help you. The method gave you a true fact (that an integral is equal to itself); it's just that the fact was useless.

Comment: Right! That makes sense

Comment: When you integrate by parts twice in succession, it is always possible to choose the variables for the second one so that you go back to the original, yielding no information.